# tf.keras.models: load_model() ValueError: Unknown layer: Functional in OpenCV/DNN module. How to use pre-trained model with old versions of tf/keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, keras, deep-learning

I did transferlearning by using MaskRCNN for multiple-object detection in an environment with:

python=3.6.12

tensorflow==1.15.3

keras==2.2.4

mrcnn==2.1

And the model works.

Now I would like to implement mrcnn real-time with my laptop camera and OpenCV.

Firstly, I would apply face detection with **res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000.caffemodel** because my mrcnn model works better if it is run on a face. I chose res10 because I have aleady used it in another project and it worked well!

Unfortunatly, I notice that MaskRCNN doesn't work with the latest version of tensorflow. Moreover, **res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000.caffemodel** doesn't work with old versions of tensorflow and I get this error: **"ValueError: Unknown layer: Functional"**.

I would like to know if it is possible to use **res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000.caffemodel**
with previous versions of tensorflow, isn't it?

Is there a way to do a porting of MaskRCNN to a more recent version of tensorflow?

Or, is there a way to use res10 with old versions of tensorflow?

A different model for face detection in opencv with a good accuracy?

A different model rather than mrcnn tha is compatible with res10?

Any advice is welcome!
Thanks!

My Resources:

https://github.com/opencv/opencv/wiki/Deep-Learning-in-OpenCV

https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-train-an-object-detection-model-with-keras/

https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2020/05/04/covid-19-face-mask-detector-with-opencv-keras-tensorflow-and-deep-learning/

Comment: .caffemodel is a model meant for the Caffe framework, how exactly are you loading this model in TensorFlow?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: `from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model

import cv2

# load our serialized face detector model from disk

prototxtPath = 'deploy.prototxt.txt'

weightsPath = 'res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000.caffemodel'

faceNet = cv2.dnn.readNet(prototxtPath, weightsPath)`

Reference: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2020/05/04/covid-19-face-mask-detector-with-opencv-keras-tensorflow-and-deep-learning/

Just remember I'm workin in an environment with:

python=3.6.12

tensorflow==1.15.3

keras==2.2.4

Comment: Hi! Attaching reference for loading Caffe models . https://colab.research.google.com/github/dortmans/ml_notebooks/blob/master/face_detection.ipynb